# Nav not showing

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS, and I wanted to start with an easy web layout I found. The web layout starts with the logo, which displays on the browser, but the `nav` I created does not. Why?

Does it have to do with the fact that I used % for the size?

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Weblayout on IJ</title>

</head>


<body>

<header class="title">

    <h1>
        Logo
    </h1>

</header>

<nav class="menu">
</nav>

</body>


</html>
```

### CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #ada6a0;
}

.title{
    color: #f3f2f2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 7%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Can you acept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add nothing to navbar what do you expect?

Extremly simple example:

```css
body{
    background-color: #ada6a0;
}

.title{
    color: #f3f2f2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 7%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">


<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Weblayout on IJ</title>


</head>


<body>

<header class="title">

    <h1>
        Logo
    </h1>

</header>

<nav class="menu">
<button>
Button 1
</button>
<button>
Button 2
</button>
<button>
Button 3
</button>
</nav>

</body>


</html>
```

If you want to see any tips i suggest to use bootstrap, so you can see how that work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some links or buttons in the nav bar for it to show up. Something like this.

```css
body{
    background-color: #ada6a0;
}

.title{
    color: #f3f2f2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 7%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">


<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Weblayout on IJ</title>


</head>


<body>

<header class="title">

    <h1>
        Logo
    </h1>

</header>

<nav class="menu">

<a href="www.google.com">Google</a> |
<a href="www.youtube.com">Youtube</a> |

</nav>

</body>


</html>
```

For more details, I used this site to help me out in most HTML related things : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp